# Interesting product in a cyclotomic field

Tags: cyclotomic-fields

Let $n$ be an integer greater $2$. What is the value of the following product for $a=3, \dots , n-1$:

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^{a-1} \zeta^{jk} \right)$$

where $\zeta$ is some complex $n$th root of unity. I can prove that:

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} \left( 1 + \sum_{j = 1}^{a-1} \zeta^{jk} \right) = 1$$

and for $a = 2$:

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^{a-1} \zeta^{jk} \right) =
\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} (1-\zeta^k) = n$$

However, I have problem with the general case.

Comment: It is maybe more advisable not to use $i$ as an index of summation when dealing with complex numbers.

Comment: I find it is $\displaystyle\frac{P(\zeta^{a-1})}{P(\zeta^{-1})}$
where $P(x) =  \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-x^k)$

Comment: I believe that your claim would imply that $\prod_{k = 1}^{p-1} \left(1 - \sum_{j = 1}^{p-1} \zeta^{jk} \right) = 1$ for an odd prime $p$. And this contradicts every example I've computed. Here is the sketch of the proof. Let $a \in \{1, 2, \dots, p-1\}$. Then $x \mapsto ax$ is a permutation of $\{1, 2, \dots, p-1\}$. Therefore: $P(\zeta^{a}) = \prod_{k = 1}^{p-1} (1 - (\zeta^{a})^k) = \prod_{k = 1}^{p-1} (1-\zeta^{ak}) = \prod_{k = 1}^{p-1} (1 - \zeta^k) = p$. Therefore $P(\zeta^{a-1}) = P(\zeta^{-1}) = p$.

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you for your comment. Could you give a sketch of the argument? This results seem to contradict all the examples I've computed, as I explained above.